# Data dog case sensitive log search

Tags: logging, datadog

Is there any way via we can search case-sensitive keywords in our logs inside data dog content.

eg: if our log has a string `phone is updated` 

 and I search for `*Phone*` I should get 0 result

but if I search `*phone*` I should get 1 result

Already gone through the following doc unable to figure out
https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/trace_explorer/query_syntax/
https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/explorer/search_syntax/

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Unfortunately, no. The log search is not case-sensitive.

But the [attributes](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/log_configuration/attributes_naming_convention/) are case-sensitive, if you add this message to an `attribute` like `status`, you can run:

```
service:your-service @status:Phone
```

And you will only get messages that have `Phone` in the `status` attribute.